# BURN - SQL Server 2014 Installation takes almost 50 minutes to complete

Tags: wix, sql-server-2014, burn

As a prerequisite, I have chained SQL Server 2014 express edition to be installed before my application is installed.

The SQL Installation is successful. However, it takes close to 50 minutes to complete the SQL Installation and proceed to the installation of my application. Is it normal ? Does SQL actually takes around 50 min. to install. I don’t think so.

Here is the command I have:

```
<ExePackage Id="SQLExpress2014"
                  Cache="no"
                  Compressed="yes"
                  PerMachine="yes"
                  Permanent="yes"
                  Vital="yes"
                  SourceFile="Resources\SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe"
                  InstallCommand="/ACTION=Install /Q /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /FEATURES=SQLEngine /INSTANCENAME=$(var.SqlServerInstance) /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=BUILTIN\Administrators /SECURITYMODE=SQL /SAPWD=Password /SQLCOLLATION=SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
                  UninstallCommand="/ACTION=Uninstall /Q /FEATURES=SQLEngine /INSTANCENAME=$(var.SqlServerInstance) "
                  RepairCommand="/ACTION=Repair /Q /FEATURES=SQLEngine / INSTANCENAME=$(var.SqlServerInstance) /FEATURES=SQLENGINE"
                  DetectCondition="SqlInstanceFound"
                  InstallCondition="RadioButton1 = 1 AND VersionNT64 AND NOT SqlInstanceFound"/>
```

The log file does not seem to have any relevant information either.
Below is the excerpt from the Log file which shows the time lag.

```
09/01/2016 00:27:25.295 Attempting to get execution timestamp
09/01/2016 00:27:25.295 Timestamp: 20160901_002724
09/01/2016 00:27:25.295 Attempting to launch local setup.exe
09/01/2016 00:27:25.316 Attempting to launch process C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\SQLServer2014\setup.exe
09/01/2016 01:18:46.100 Process returned exit code: 0x00000000
09/01/2016 01:18:46.100 Local setup.exe returned exit code: 0x00000000
09/01/2016 01:18:46.141 Setup closed with exit code: 0x00000000
09/01/2016 01:18:46.155 ======================================================================
```

Highlighted are the two statements which shows the time lag.
Is there anything that I am doing wrong or is there any way I can reduce this time.

There is not an issue of other processes or anything as this is a fresh machine on which I tried installing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

TIA
Ashutosh

Comment: You'd probably get better answers on dba.stackexchange.com, mostly devs on here

Comment: Since its more of a WIX Question then a SQL Question, I thought it should belong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the installation "/UpdateEnabled=0". This should significantly cut down on install time. Also the logs for SQL should be located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log`

Comment: It did not cut down the time SIGNIFICANTLY. However did bring it down by 10 min.